# Getting custom attribute from an Exception thrown during testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I'm using JUnit4 to test my code.

Now, I'm aware that the following annotation allows me to expect an exception of a certain type

```
@Test(expected = NipException.class)
```

However, I have an 'errorCode' property in my exception class which I would also like to verify.

This is because the same exception is thrown at three places in the same method with different error codes.

How do I access 'errorCode' of the thrown exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just catch the exception and assert the `errorCode`.

Comment: +1. That works. Thanks! However, I was looking for a way to do it without having the try/catch of the Exception in my test method. Else, why specify 'expected' in the annotation?

Comment: True, but unfortunately, using the current version of JUnit4 [`@Test.expected()`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected%28%29) it is not possible to do what you're trying to.

Comment: I suspected that, but was hoping to be proved wrong. Thanks for your help!